What does `fit_transform` do in the context of Scikit Learn PCA?
I don't understand what fit_transform does compared to fit in the context of Scikit Learn and PCA.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#

PCA takes some data and attempts to measure a set of eigenvectors, where each vector is orthogonal to all others and aligned in the direction of maximum remaining variance.
Put another way, the first eigenvector found is oriented along the axis of maximal data variance.
What transformation does fit_transform do, and what interpretation does it have in the context of PCA?
In other words, what transformation is being done by the transform step?

The documentation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.transform

In simple terms:

fit(X): Calculates the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix of X using eigendecomposition. You can retrieve the eigenvectors after you have fit the PCA (pca.fit(X)) via pca.components_.
transform(X): Converts the input data from the input vector space to the PCA vector space. That is - the vector space defined by the eigenvectors obtained from the PCA algorithm. The transformed data are commonly referred to as the principal components (PCs).
fit_transform(X): Combines both steps - first finding the eigenvectors and then projecting the data onto them.

In practice, Scikit-learn’s PCA implementation uses Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) on X, which gives you both the eigenvectors and principal components in one step during fit(). However, if you have new data to project into the principal component space, you’ll need the transform() method to do that projection.
Note on Scikit-learn's terminology: eigenvectors = components_

I've had a play around with it and one thing still confuses me. fit_transform seems to produce the transformed data as an output, but it does not provide any way to obtain the eigenvectors themselves. Have I misunderstood how to get both pieces of information at once?

btw: The "exact" answer to my question is that transform converts the input data from the input vector space to the PCA vector space. That is - the vector space defined by the eigenvectors obtained from the PCA algorithm. (Which as you mention, is SVD by default, apparently.)

Thanks I updated the answer with your more precise description. I also added how to retrieve the eigenvectors.

The difference between fit and fit_transform is when you use the first it just does the math to transform the data only when you use transform that the data is retured. So as you might have guessed fit_transform does both in a single go.

That doesn't answer my question. As you have phrased it, I am asking what does the transform step do?

Notebook
Here are some notes from a notebook which I created to explore what transformations PCA was actually applying.
Key point:

The transformation applied is a rotation. (A rotation matrix transform.)
The input data is rotated or projected along the eigenbasis obtained from PCA

The output of fit_transform is the input data with some transformation applied. We want to know exactly what transformation is being applied to the input to create the output.
pca_output_transformed_0 = pca.fit_transform(uv.T) # uv is some input, see later

It turns out the following is equivalent to the above.
pca_output = pca.fit(uv.T)
pca_rotation_matrix = pca_output.components_
pca_xy = pca_rotation_matrix @ uv

In other words pca_xy == pca_output_transformed_0.
In more detail
import math
import numpy

x = numpy.random.normal(0.0, 1.0, size=10000)
y = numpy.random.normal(0.0, 0.1, size=10000)

xy = numpy.vstack((x, y))

theta = math.pi / 180.0 * 10.0
s = math.sin(theta)
c = math.cos(theta)
rotation_matrix = numpy.array([[c, -s], [s, c]])
rotation_matrix_inv = numpy.linalg.inv(rotation_matrix)

uv = rotation_matrix @ xy

Timeseries x, y
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()

plt.plot(xy[0], label='x')
plt.plot(xy[1], label='y')

plt.xlabel('sample')
plt.ylabel('currency-pair')
plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), ncol=1)
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
plt.show()


Timeseries u, v
plt.figure()

plt.plot(uv[0], label='u')
plt.plot(uv[1], label='v')

plt.xlabel('sample')
plt.ylabel('currency-pair')
plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), ncol=1)
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
plt.show()


Phasespace x, y
plt.figure()

plt.scatter(xy[0], xy[1], s=1)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.xlim(-5, 5)
plt.ylim(-5, 5)
plt.show()


Phasespace u, v
plt.figure()

plt.scatter(uv[0], uv[1], s=1)
plt.xlabel('u')
plt.ylabel('v')
plt.xlim(-5, 5)
plt.ylim(-5, 5)
plt.show()


PCA Decomposition
import sklearn.decomposition

pca = sklearn.decomposition.PCA()
pca_output = pca.fit(uv.T)
pca_output_transformed_0 = pca.fit_transform(uv.T)
pca_output_transformed_1 = pca.transform(uv.T)

# these are the same (output all zero within rounding error)
pca_output_transformed_0 - pca_output_transformed_1

pca_rotation_matrix = pca_output.components_
pca_xy = pca_rotation_matrix @ uv

Phasespace pca_xy
plt.figure()

plt.scatter(pca_xy[0], pca_xy[1], s=1)
plt.xlabel('pca_x')
plt.ylabel('pca_y')
plt.xlim(-5, 5)
plt.ylim(-5, 5)
plt.show()


Phasespace pca_output_transformed_0
plt.figure()

plt.scatter(pca_output_transformed_0.T[0], pca_output_transformed_0.T[1], s=1)
plt.xlabel('pca_output_transformed_0.T [y]')
plt.ylabel('pca_output_transformed_0.T [x]')
plt.xlim(-5, 5)
plt.ylim(-5, 5)
plt.show()



One comment which I should perhaps add. These signals have zero mean. If you apply PCA to some signals with non-zero mean, then the mean value will be subtracted from those signals in the transformed output.
